# How do I get boolean from URL parameter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

Exactly what I want is isActive which is in the NavLink function in the React Router Dom. However, I want to render SVG conditionally. Do you have any other solution? Thank you.

````
      <NavLink
        to="/"
        style={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeStyle : undefined)}
      >
        Home
        <NavLine className="active-line" />
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink
        to="/asd"
        style={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeStyle : undefined)}
      >
        Work
        <NavLine className="active-line" />
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink
        to="/dsa"
        style={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeStyle : undefined)}
      >
        About
        <NavLine className="active-line" />
      </NavLink>
    </div>```
````